# Plotting OMI satelliate daily data using Basemap package

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, hdf

**OMI** (Ozone Monitoring Instrument) measures the key air quality components such as nitrogen dioxide(NO2), ozone(O3). The daily columnO3 file which I downloaded [here](http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/mirador/granlist.pl?dataSet=OMNO2G&version=003&allversion=003&keyword=omno2&pointLocation=(-90,-180),(90,180)&location=(-90,-180),(90,180)&searchType=Location&event=&startTime=2004-10-01&endTime=2016-06-15%2023:59:59&search=&CGISESSID=18bd3c7fb47ceeb1e5c1e9f8139efd0c&nr=4246&temporalres=1%20day&prodpg=http://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datacollection/OMNO2G_V003.html&longname=OMI/Aura%20NO2%20Total%20and%20Tropospheric%20Column%20Daily%20L2%20Global%20Gridded%200.25%20degree%20x%200.25%20degree%20V3&granulePresentation=ungrouped&order=a&page=1&pageSet=0) represented the global distribution of ozone column concentration of troposphere.

The file's size is about 90Mb. Anyone interested can download any of them.

The data was uploaded here in the shape of (15, 720, 1440)

- 15 is the **Number of candidate scenes**
- 1440 is the X-dimension, longitudes [-180:180] from left to right
- 720 is the Y-dimension, latitudes [-90:90] from bottom to top

Wiht **h5py** and matplotlib.basemap, here is my attempt:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

file = h5py.File("OMI-Aura_L2-OMNO2_2016m0529t1759-o63150_v003-2016m0531t023832.he5", 'r')
dataFields=file['HDFEOS']['GRIDS']['ColumnAmountNO2']['Data Fields']
SDS_NAME='ColumnAmountNO2'
data=dataFields[SDS_NAME]
map_label=data.attrs['Units'].decode()

fv=data.attrs['_FillValue']
mv=data.attrs['MissingValue']
offset=data.attrs['Offset']
scale=data.attrs['ScaleFactor']

lat=dataFields['Latitude'][:][0]
min_lat=np.min(lat)
max_lat=np.max(lat)
lon=dataFields['Longitude'][:][0]
min_lon=np.min(lon)
max_lon=np.max(lon)     

dataArray=data[:][1]
dataArray[dataArray==fv]=np.nan
dataArray[dataArray==mv]=np.nan
dataArray = scale * (dataArray - offset)    

fig = plt.figure()
data_mask = np.ma.masked_array(data[0], np.isnan(data[0]))
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='l',llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat = 90,llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon = 180)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 120., 30.), labels=[1, 0, 0, 0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180, 180., 45.), labels=[0, 0, 0, 1])
my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('gist_stern_r')
my_cmap.set_under('w')
m.pcolormesh(lon, lat, data_mask,latlon=True, cmap=my_cmap)
cb = m.colorbar()
cb.set_label(map_label)
plt.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

Figure shows like this:

[image]

Using **Panoply**, with candidate 0, figure shows like this:

[image]

#### My question

- How to set the *candidate scenes* to represent the global distribution daily(What is the meaning of candidate scenes? Does it correspond to orbit tracks?)
- What's wrong with my code which not showing the correct figure

#### My target

The figure below was clipped from Internet. That's my target style!

Any advice or tutorial guide would be appreciate!

[image]

Comment: There are some weird things going on with your data; e.g. `min_lon` is `-1.2676506e+30` if I run it with a random data set from the site that you linked to. That might explain why everything is cropped in the top-right corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Latitude` and `Longitude` variables have missing values too, which are -1.2676506e+30 and thus cause the large xrange and yrange in your plots. Also, note that the `_FillValue` and `MissingValue` attributes are lists, so your replacement with NaNs went wrong.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

def array_with_nans(h5var):
    """ Extracts the array and replaces fillvalues and missing values with Nans
    """
    array = h5var[:] # not very efficient

    # _FillValue and MissingValue attributes are lists
    for value in h5var.attrs['MissingValue']:
        array[array==value]=np.nan

    for value in h5var.attrs['_FillValue']:
        array[array==value]=np.nan

    return array


#file = h5py.File("OMI-Aura_L2-OMNO2_2016m0529t1759-o63150_v003-2016m0531t023832.he5", 'r')
file = h5py.File("OMI-Aura_L2G-OMNO2G_2004m1001_v003-2012m0714t175148.he5", 'r')
dataFields=file['HDFEOS']['GRIDS']['ColumnAmountNO2']['Data Fields']
SDS_NAME='ColumnAmountNO2'
data=dataFields[SDS_NAME]
map_label=data.attrs['Units'].decode()

offset=data.attrs['Offset'][0]
print("offset: {}".format(offset))
scale=data.attrs['ScaleFactor'][0]
print("scale: {}".format(scale))

candidate = 0

dataArray=array_with_nans(data)[candidate]    
dataArray = scale * (dataArray - offset) 

lat = array_with_nans(dataFields['Latitude'])[candidate]
lon = array_with_nans(dataFields['Longitude'])[candidate]

fig = plt.figure()
data_mask = np.ma.masked_array(dataArray, np.isnan(dataArray))


m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='l',llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat = 90,llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon = 180)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 120., 30.), labels=[1, 0, 0, 0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180, 180., 45.), labels=[0, 0, 0, 1])
my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('gist_stern_r')
my_cmap.set_under('w')
m.pcolormesh(lon, lat, data_mask,latlon=True, cmap=my_cmap)
cb = m.colorbar()
cb.set_label(map_label)
plt.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

It's better to ask only one question per post and you are unlikely to get an answer on what the *candidate scene* means. You may find an answer to this in the [product documentation](http://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/uui/datasets/OMNO2G_V003/summary#documentation)